# XACML - How to express "not male" rather than "not gender == male"

Tags: xacml, alfa

The function not in XACML asks for a boolean argument. However, I want to express a policy like "not string" such as "not male". I can't use "not gender == male" to instead that. I searched google and stackoverflow, but I failed to solve this problem. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a XACML request, you always send a set of attributes with one or more values. You would either send:

- an attribute with identifier gender, datatype string, and category subject, or
- an attribute with identifier male, datatype boolean, and category subject.

Either way you still send an attribute. In one case the value is a string. In the other the value is a string. In the explanation below, I take the string approach. If you want the boolean approach, just replace gender=="male" with male.

Note that in XACML, attributes may possibly not have a value. This makes XACML booleans more than just boolean. Male could be true, false, or undefined. Keep that in mind when you write a policy / rule.

To express negative conditions e.g. not(gender==male), you have two options:

- either the set of possible values is finite e.g. true/false, male/female, hot/warm/cold and you are happy building a policy or rule per case.
- or the set of possible values is too long or infinite e.g. a numerical value or a list of citizenships (180+ of those).

In the former case you can write the following (pseudo-code in [ALFA](https://www.axiomatics.com/axiomatics-alfa-plugin-for-eclipse.html)):

```
policy checkGender{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule male{
        target clause gender=="male"
        permit
    }
    rule female{
        target clause gender=="female"
        permit
    }
    /**
     * Optionally add a catch all case
     */
    rule other{
        target clause ... // Here you'd have to define other checks you are interested in
    }
}
```

In the latter case, you need to write a negative condition. To do that you need to use a XACML condition. Since XACML conditions only live inside rules, you need to go down to the XACML Rule level.

```
policy checkGender{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule notMale{
        condition not(gender=="male")
        permit
    }
}
```